# Javascript and dynamic variables... Again

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

So I'm a total JS newb.  I've read a hundred other posts, tried their solutions, and I can't seem to get it to work to save my life.

Here's the problem:

I have JS and ajax that work.  But only on explicitly expressed values.  The minute I try to abstract it to handle all the variables it stops working.

I'm also open to a better way of doing this, but this is what I've figured out so far based on my limited knowledge.

I have a very very large form.  Nearly 400 hundred fields for "in the field" data acquisition on mobile phones.  Bandwidth isn't an issue, but stability and reliability are, so the form is supposed to send each piece of data over as it's entered, allowing for changes and alterations, until it's ready to be submitted. Until that time it sends back the same info which is then used to display a green dot to verify that the data has in fact been stored. So for every form field, there is a `<span>` with an id named after it in the form FormFieldAStatus.  I've included it below.

Form snippet:

```
<input type="text" class="form-textbox validate[required]" id="input_1" name="formFieldA" size="20" onchange="saveData(); readData()" />
<span class="ajax-success" id="formFieldAStatus"></span>
```

Here's the code that works:

```
function readData() {
  new Ajax.Request('AjaxRead.php', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: $('Worksheet').serialize(true),
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
      var icon = '<img src="images/greendot.png" align="bottom" style="margin-right:5px;">';
      if (transport.responseText) {
        var json=transport.responseText.evalJSON();
        if(json.formFieldA) { 
          var status = $('formFieldAStatus'); 
          status.update(icon); } 
        if(json.formFieldB) { 
          var status = $('formFieldBStatus'); 
          status.update(icon); } 
        if(json.formFieldC) { 
          var status = $('formFieldCStatus'); 
          status.update(icon); } 
      }
    },
    onFailure:function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
  });
}
```

Seriously.  I'm not putting 400 of those lines in to check every field.  That's nuts.

Here's the code that should work but doesn't.

```
function readData() {
  new Ajax.Request('AjaxRead.php', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: $('Worksheet').serialize(true),
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
      var icon = '<img src="images/greendot.png" align="bottom" style="margin-right:5px;">';
      if (transport.responseText) {
        var json=transport.responseText.evalJSON();
        for(var key in json) {
          if(!json[key]=='') {
            var statusName=key+'Status';

// Take your pick of the following. I've tried them all.                

            var status = $(statusName);
            var status = $(window[statusName]);
            var status = $(key+'Status');
            var status = $(window[key+'Status']);
            eval("var status = $('"+key+"Status');");

// Did any of them work ever?

            status.update(icon); }
        }
      }
    },
    onFailure:function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
  });
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  And if there is a better way to do this, then I'm all ears.

Cheers.

Latest details:

I added this:

```
console.log('statusname: '+statusName);
console.log('status: '+status);
console.log('status Object: '+Object.inspect(status));
```

And it spat out:

```
statusname: fieldNameAStatus 
status: [object HTMLElement] 
status Object: <span id="fieldNameAStatus" class="ajax-success">
```

for each of the methods I was trying...

the minute I uncomment this:

```
status.update(icon);
```

I get this instead:

```
statusname: formIDStatus 
status: null 
status Object: null
```

That's weird, right?

Ok. So now that I have the console.log thing down, (personal aside, thankyouthankyouthankyouthankyouthankyouthankyouthankyouthankyou for educating me about it), I decided to take a look at what it shows when I use the working manually specified code for each field.

```
status: [object HTMLElement]
status Object: <span id="fieldNameAStatus" class="ajax-success">
```

Here's what we have:

Working code:
keys are read, status object created, which is an html string defining the `<span>` it should, and updates with no problems.

Non-working:
keys are read, status object created, which is an html string defining the `<span>` it should but the call to update the object kills it on the first iteration of the loop.

What now?

Comment: What JS framework are you using?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to inspect the values in the loop in in the `onSuccess` callback?

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log` within the callback?

Comment: Sharp eye Matt.  Yes, I'm using Prototype. I knew I forgot to mention something.  I've inherited a form that makes heavy use of it already and I'm adding my own bits to it.

Comment: I've tried to access the console directly, But chrome didn't show anything out of the ordinary.  I fired up FF and installed firebug, and that didn't show me much more.  Prototype, from what I've gathered, doesn't like to reveal it's errors easily.  I found a debugging script and that seemed to add a bit more info, but nothing usable to my inexperienced eyes. There's a couple of firebug errors and a bunch from jotform, which is how I guess the form was made.  And my ajax requests which are pushing and pulling the correct info.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var statusName=json[key]+'Status';
```

It looks like you're just grabbing the key and trying to use that as opposed to the value. Also make sure to perform a json.hasOwnProperty(key) when using "for in". If you `console.log(!json[key]=='')` after the for what is the output?

Comment: Well, the key is the value I'm after, really.  I want the field's name so that I can identify that it's the correct one to update on the page and then set the correct status <span> using an id built from the field name and the "Status" designation. When I do the console.log(!json[key]=='') it just says true.

Comment: What does 'console.log($(statusName));' output when placed after "var statusName=key+'Status';"? At some point the the resolution is breaking down. It's possible that you don't have elements with that id.

Comment: Here's a bit more now that I know the beauty of freaking console.log.  Seriously, how have I never known that before? So. Much. Better. So I threw this in there just for kicks: console.log('statusname: '+statusName);       console.log('status1: '+status1);       console.log('status1 Object: '+Object.inspect(status1));

Comment: And it spat out:

statusname: policyNumberStatus
status: [object HTMLElement]
status Object: <span id="policyNumberStatus" class="ajax-success">

for each of the methods I was trying...

the minute I uncomment this:

status.update(icon);

I get this instead:

statusname: formIDStatus
status: null
status Object: null

Comment: So for some reason I'm getting the value of icon, which is the html to indicate success as the, I presume object, that represents it.  Am I close?

Comment: Without formating this is getting difficult to follow. Can you update the OP with the new information?

Comment: Ok.  So I figured it out... but the site won't let me post an answer for a few more hours. I'm still to newb i guess.  I'll post a full answer later but for now, if one of the fields being passed doesn't have a <span> to update, the whole thing chokes. This whole time I hadn't made one for the form itself.  It doesn't need it, but now it works. Finit.

Comment: You can always check the result of $(statusName) and make sure is valid before trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

```
var statusName = json[key] + 'Status';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  It works.  I figured it out.  Turns out that it was dying when one of the fields on the form was getting passed but there was no `span` for it to put anything.  It just so happened that the very first one it came across was the form itself.  I don't particularly need the form name but the JS functionality the form came with breaks if it's not there.  I couldn't get my if statement that looks to see if the field is empty or not to ignore it, so it stays.  No biggy.

I wouldn't have been able to figure that out with out the clue in to console.log.  Saved my bacon.

Thanks again.  Here's the final code:

```
function readData() {
  new Ajax.Request('AjaxRead.php', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: $('Worksheet').serialize(true),
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
      var icon = '<img src="images/success.png" align="bottom" style="margin-right:5px;">';
      var noicon = '';
      if (transport.responseText) {
        var json=transport.responseText.evalJSON();
        for(var key in json) {
          var statusName=key+'Status';
          var status = $(statusName); 
          if(!json[key]=='') {
            status.update(icon); }
          else {
            status.update(noicon); }
        }
      }
    },
    onFailure:function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
  });
}
```

Where this is the HTML to update;

```
<span class="ajax-success" id="fieldNameAStatus"></span>
```

Cheers